Schedule a task with admin privileges Windows 10
I feel like this should be easy but I am not making any further progress.  I have seen the other post mentioning Windows 7 and UAC prompts but the accepted solution on that did not post work for me.  Maybe windows 10 works different to windows 7.  I tried other solution in the post too such as running it as SYSTEM, local admin, domain admin.
I am trying to run a batch to create symbolic links which will need elevated privileges on a standard user.  I read one way to do this is to create a scheduled task with highest privileges to be run on demand.
A "user account is unknown" error kept appearing when trying to create the task and setting the user as a local admin on the computer.  When running task scheduler as administrator I was able to create the task but when ran the command prompt never appeared to ask for a folder path.
I can get the task to run but no user input appears from the batch set /p var prompt.  If I run the task as the standard user it works as expected but elevated privileges are needed to run the batch file.
This may be an XY problem and there is a simpler way to do this but I need to avoid using the "runas/save cred" option.
Any advice is appreciated.
